# CHECK with ^[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{6}$ - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, database-design, check-constraints

```
CREATE TABLE PARTICIPANTE(
    pasaporte NVARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    nombre NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    sexo CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    fecNac DATE NOT NULL,
    codPais NVARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_PARTICIPANTE PRIMARY KEY (pasaporte),
    CONSTRAINT FK_PAIS_PARTICIPANTE FOREIGN KEY (codPais) REFERENCES PAIS(codigo),
    CONSTRAINT CHK_PASAPORTE CHECK (pasaporte like '^\[A-Z\]{3}\[0-9\]{6}$')
)
```

The CONSTRAINT CHK_PASAPORTE doesn't work when I try to insert the data.

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CHK_PASAPORTE". The conflict occurred in database "OMA", table "dbo.PARTICIPANTE", column 'pasaporte'.

Example

```sql
insert into PARTICIPANTE (pasaporte,nombre,sexo,fecNac,codPais) value ('JPN865653','Noguchi','F','20000104','JPN');
```

Can someone explain to me why this doesn't work and how can I fix it?

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support Regex, so your `LIKE` expression isn't doing what you *think* it is. Your pattern would only permit strings that start with `^\ `, then have a letter or reverse solidus (`\ `) , then have `{3}\ `, followed by a digit or reverse solidus, and then finally `{6}$` (ignore trailing spaces due to markdown limitations).

Comment: Anyway, the regex is wrong, it must be `'^[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{6}$'`

Comment: So, for example, the value `'^\H{3}\7{6}$'` would be acceptable, as would `'^\\{3}\\{6}$'`.

Answer (score 2):

As I mention in the comments, SQL Server has no (in built) support for Regex, it only has *basic* pattern matching, which is explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#arguments).

Fortunately, the logic you are after appears to be quite simple; 3 letters followed by 6 digits. This can be achieved with the following constraint:

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.PARTICIPANTE ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_PASAPORTE CHECK (pasaporte LIKE '[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]');
```

Note that if you require the value to only contain uppercase values, you'll need to `COLLATE` the value to a collation that is case sensitive *and* orders upper case letters first, then lowercase, and finally alphabetically (Binary collations are one such one that does this).